# Preventing duplicate applications

Tags: base-url, cypress

Our web-based ERP application prevents a user from opening a second browser window with the same URL, via a bunch of JavaScript that checks window names etc.

The point is, you can only open *one* instance of the application and if you attempt to open another, you get a warning message and the application refuses to open.

When I use

```
cy.visit('our application')
```

1. the Cypress main window gets updated with our application's URL
2. the Cypress browser window gets updated with our application's URL

This immediately flags our application as trying to open a second copy which then prevents it from opening in the Cypress-controlled browser, which prevents any further testing!

Is there any way to prevent this happening. I have tried using various flavours of `baseUrl` in the `cypress.json` file, but nothing has been successful.

Anyone have any useful ideas?

Comment: Does it make a difference if running Cypress in Electron or Chrome (ref button below login)?

Comment: It does not...
The problem arises from the fact that the Cypress application kicks off an implementation e.g.
    http://myapplication.com/__/#/tests/integration\my_spec.js
followed by opening a browser window with the same URL e.g.
    http://myapplication.com/
Since our application is built to prevent opening multiple copies of itself, the version in the Cypress application *prevents* the version in the browser from opening...

Comment: Ok, the reason I ask is - Cypress main window is an electron desktop app not a browser. I do not see how `cy.visit('our application')` in a spec can change any attributes on the Cypress main window. What am I not seeing here?